# Correct way to deal with optimistic lock in jOOQ without records

Tags: java, spring, jooq, optimistic-locking

I want to implement optimistic locking in my project for concurrent requests. I'm using Java 17, Spring and jooq.

While reading the documentation, I found out that jOOQ has support for optimistic locking out of the box, but I decided to implement it myself, because I don't want to use jooq records (I am `JdbcTemplate` adept, and I really love this way of writing persistence layer).
As a result, I expanded my table with a version column, and when updating an entity, I check that the version is not different and increment the version.

The main problem is that I don't understand how to work with exceptions correctly. When updating, I want to understand what went wrong: we didn't find the entity, or the version is different.

Now, I have something like this in my update method:

```
public void update(SomeEntity value) throws SomeException {
        boolean isUpdated = dsl.update(TABLE_NAME)
                .set(TABLE_NAME.FIELD1, value.getField1())
                .set(TABLE_NAME.LAST_UPDATE, OffsetDateTime.now())
                .set(TABLE_NAME.VERSION, TABLE_NAME.VERSION.add(1))
                .where(TABLE_NAME.ID.eq(value.getId())
                        .and(TABLE_NAME.VERSION.eq(value.getVersion())))
                .execute() > 0;

        if (!isUpdated) {
            throw new SomeException();
        }
    }
```

In this case, I can't understand what went wrong: there is no entity with such id, or the version defers.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how to implement this functionality correctly.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ's own optimistic locking implementation doesn't distinguish between these two cases because the distinction isn't relevant (and it would be hard to get right with a single query and without pessimistic locks).

Why is it irrelevant? Given the assumption that you're not just passing around random IDs, the ID you have must have existed *at some point*, so the only reason why it doesn't exist anymore is because someone deleted the record. Hence, it is just another case of where optimistic locking should raise your `SomeException`, not much different from when the version has changed.

Comment: I agree, it sounds logical, thank you!